# String.toLocaleUpperCase(): Set locale on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, ecmascript-intl

The JavaScript String `toLocaleUpperCase()` method is supposed to account for case mapping on different locales, like Turkish (i is not mapper to dotless I, but to dotted İ in Turkish).

However, it seems the locale is captured from the OS only: I don't see a way to set up the locale. So if I am using a en-US OS and want to `toLocaleUpperCase()` a Turkish string in "tr", it will return the en-US version (dotless I, not dotted İ).

Assuming I am using Node.js compiled with INTL (https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Intl), how could I define the locale to `toLocaleUpperCase()`?

Comment: Note that you can have a different locale per process, `LOCALE=tr_TR.UTF-8` for example. Looking at the documentation for `Intl`, it wasn't clear whether it's an object that can be instantiated and used as a context for string operations... but that's probably the direction you want to look in.

Comment: Thanks @david, I'll check that. However, I want to be able to switch locales according to client requests. By setting a locale per process, it would run permanently with that locale. For a properly internationalized sw, it would be necessary to use `toLocaleUpperCase()` according to the different user requests. I'll see if this can be changed dynamically in runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't quite an answer right now.  But ECMA-402 now specifies (as of the spec's 2nd edition) the behavior of `String.prototype.toLocaleUpperCase`.  ECMA-402 changes the function to take a `locale` argument (`undefined`, string, or arraylike of locales) -- similar to what `Number.prototype.toLocaleString` and the various other locale-sensitive functions in ECMA-262 take, when modified by ECMA-402 -- and behaves consistent with that locale.  Once Node implements that ([it doesn't right now](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/77ddcfb3e095d025e7a5126d398b0493e722dbb9/src/js/string.js#L326)), you can simply change

```
var str = "bira";
str.toLocaleUpperCase(); // "BIRA"
```

to

```
var str = "bira";
str.toLocaleUpperCase("tr-TR"); // BİRA
```

and be on your way.

(Disclaimer: I don't know Turkish at all, I just picked a word containing "i" off a Turkish word list, and I'm *presuming* locale-sensitive uppercasing works the way I expect it does, for the purpose of the example above.)